# How to draw a OES texture to a Surface direct without color format change in Android

Tags: texture2d, android-virtualdisplay

I have an OES texture record from VirtualDisplay, for some reason, I need draw the texture to another Surface from somewhere else. The problem is I want keep the origin OES texture's color format, or using a NV21 color format;
I can find many answer to using egl to draw the OES texture using texture2d, but all their fragment shader will produce a RGBA color format texture!

So is there any way just clone the OES texture to the Surface or draw on the Surface using NV21 color format?